# ControllerServiceInstantiationException trying to upgrade NiFi from 1.5.0 to 1.8.0

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to upgrade NiFi from 1.5.0 to 1.8.0.

The upgrade starts up successfully when the default flow.xml.gz is used.  However, when the flow.xml.gz from 1.5.0 replaces the default one in the 1.8.0 in the conf directory, there are a bunch of ControllerServiceInstantiationException exceptions in the logs that are similar.  The first one of these is:

```
2019-01-24 14:39:20,714 ERROR [main] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceProvider Could not create Controller Service of type org.apache.nifi.ssl.StandardSSLContextService for ID e7800100-015d-1000-7210-d5961d784f27; creating "Ghost" implementation
org.apache.nifi.controller.exception.ControllerServiceInstantiationException: Unable to find bundle for coordinate org.apache.nifi:nifi-ssl-context-service-nar:1.5.0
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceProvider.createControllerService(StandardControllerServiceProvider.java:126)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.createControllerService(FlowController.java:3869)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.ControllerServiceLoader.createControllerService(ControllerServiceLoader.java:207)
...
```

Unpacking the flow.xml.gz, there is the StandardSSLContextService config and it references version 1.5.0:

```
<controllerService>
        <id>eae39ebf-6d70-34db-aafd-bcbe66eead6f</id>
        <name>StandardSSLContextService</name>
        <comment/>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.ssl.StandardSSLContextService</class>
        <bundle>
          <group>org.apache.nifi</group>
          <artifact>nifi-ssl-context-service-nar</artifact>
          <version>1.5.0</version>
        </bundle>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <property>
          <name>Keystore Filename</name>
          <value>/opt/cermt-processor/templates/twlserver.jks</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>Keystore Password</name>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>key-password</name>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>Keystore Type</name>
          <value>JKS</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>Truststore Filename</name>
          <value>/opt/cermt-processor/templates/truststore.jks</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>Truststore Password</name>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>Truststore Type</name>
          <value>JKS</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>SSL Protocol</name>
          <value>TLS</value>
        </property>
      </controllerService>
```

In the work/nar/extensions there is this directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 24 13:14 nifi-ssl-context-service-nar-1.8.0.nar-unpacked
```

Does that make a difference?  According to the upgrade documentation, the flow.xml.gz from 1.5.0 should be backwards compatible with 1.8.0.

Suggestions for fixing this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache NiFi does make great efforts to be backward-compatible. That means a flow designed in one version should work seamlessly on the next minor version. There are [upgrade instructions available here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/1.x.0+to+1.x.0+Upgrade) and additional [Migration Guidance](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance).

The problem is that your existing `flow.xml.gz` file references the 1.5.0 version of the `StandardSSLContextService` controller service. If you deploy on a 1.8.0 (default) instance, that controller service implementation is not present (the 1.8.0 version is). You can remedy this in a couple ways:

- Manually edit the `flow.xml.gz` file to reference the 1.8.0 version of the controller service (and other components) by changing the XML values. Be aware that some components may have had properties added/changed between versions
- Add the 1.5.0 NARs (NiFi Archive) containing those components to the 1.8.0 instance `lib/`. NiFi can run multiple versions of the same component to allow for piecemeal migration. Bryan Bende [has written more](https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/05/10/apache-nifi-1-2-0-component-versioning) about this. With both versions available, your existing flow should be deployed correctly and you can change the version of the component on the canvas via the UI

Comment: Manually editing the flow.xml.gz to reference 1.8.0 eliminates those exceptions.  Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 3):

The logic during start up should be the following:

A) If the flow.xml asks for version X (1.5.0) and that versions exists, then you get that version

B) If the flow.xml asks for version X (1.5.0) and it doesn't exist, but some other version Y exists, and its the only version with the same group+artifact, then you automatically get that version

C) If the flow.xml asks for version X (1.5.0) and it doesn't exist, and two other versions Y and Z exist, then you get a ghost component because the system can't choose for you

So a normal upgrade like yours should be falling into case B where it should auto-upgrade for you.

Maybe double-check that the lib directory doesn't have two versions of nifi-ssl-context-service-nar and maybe try blowing away the work directory to ensure all NARs get unpacked fresh.

I don't think this matters, but I also noticed in your exception the service ID is not the same as the service ID in the snippet you showed from flow.xml. I assume that service also had the 1.5.0 bundle, but would be good to verift.